# the length of a random walk in two dimensions

Tags: randomness, random-walk

This is a matlab code that could generate a random walk in two dimensions of length 1000: xy = cumsum (-1+2*rand(1000,2),1).

The 'stepsize' is between $[-1,1]$. In this case, we are talking about the set of real numbers from $-1$ and $1$. The rand function in this case generates numbers between $(0,1)$ over a uniform distribution.

Question 1: 
How will I determine the range of values (in $x$ and $y$ coordinates) after covering 1000 steps?

Question 2: 
Is it possible to find the values of $a$, $b$, with at least a probability of 0.5, so that $a + bU(0,1)$ gives me a random walk where the extreme points are in the domain $X: [860,1520]$ and $Y:[-830,0]$? after 600 steps?

$U(0,1)$ means the uniform distribution over $(0,1)$.

Your insights would be very helpful.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "covers"?  After all, since each step will have (Euclidean) length between $0$ and $\sqrt{2}$, isn't it obvious what the possible range of $1000$ independent steps would be?

Comment: sorry, I am being loose with my definition. I meant 'span'.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "span"?  If you mean the possible extremes, then we're right back to my first comment: isn't the answer perfectly obvious?  I therefore have to suppose you're asking something less trivial than that.

Comment: Well, I am not sure if the answer is trivial or not. Yes, the possible 'realizations'. Because in fact it may or may not reach the extreme values also?

Comment: Well, that's what I'm trying to ask: if you're asking only about the "span" or "range," that is not a question about probabilities, but only possibilities--and those ought to be very clear.  Although it is true that attaining extreme distances of either $0$ or $1000\sqrt{2}$ are improbable, their probabilities clearly are not zero.  If you are trying to ask a question about probabilities, though, then your question needs to be more clearly framed and articulated: exactly what probability or probabilities are you inquiring about?

Comment: Thanks for your input. Is it possible to solve the problem above with a probability of 0.5, for example? So, for the question (for example), is it possible to find $a$ and $b$ so that the random walk can reach the extreme values stated with probability 0.5?

Comment: Of course!  You will need to edit your post to ask your modified question.

Comment: By "range of values" might you mean *distribution* of the values?

Comment: Yes, distribution of values. Although, thinking about it now, is it possible to have 'range' in the sense of 'domain and range'?